# canvas.toDataURLWithMultiplier is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to export an image 4x the size of the canvas one.

With

```
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
```

I get the image set to the size of the canvas

However when I try

```
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURLWithMultiplier(4);
```

I get the error "canvas.toDataURLWithMultiplier is not a function"

Here is my function below.

```
$('.preview').on('click touchstart', function() {

  // save canvas image as data url (png format by default)
  canvas.isGrabMode = false;
  canvas.setZoom(1.0);
  canvas.viewportTransform = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0];
  // var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURLWithMultiplier(4);
  // so it can be saved as an image
  document.getElementById('previewImg').src = dataURL;

  canvas.renderAll();

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({
  format: 'png',
  multiplier: 4
});
```

Use `multiplier` property in [toDataURL()](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#toDataURL).